# Win'7 UART BlueTooth Goes Silent After Four Thousand Bytes

Tags: c#, bluetooth, uart

I have a small embedded system which I have rigged up with a debug routine to send the exact same byte over and over to the PC across a bluetooth connection.

The speed in question is 921600 bps

After successfully receiving about four thousand bytes (give or take a few hundred) my app sees no more from Win7

I am totally confident that the bytes (i.e., a whole lot more than four thousand) continue to be sent well after the stream disappears from my app

I am highly suspicious that Windows is somehow, for some reason, not delivering what the bluetooth is receiving.

I can state with total confidence that...

- The app does display the first four thousand some-odd bytes properly
- The app Is not displaying anything after that
- The external box continues to send the bytes

My suspicion about Win'7  has been heightened because

- My external transmitting box continued after I stopped the app.
- After two minutes, I stopped the external transmitting box
- At that moment, both PC and small box were not interacting
- With both systems stopped, (for several minutes) I restarted the PC app
- With no transmitted bytes, the app received 941 bytes, from where, I don't really know
- Those bytes were from a previous session (I'm sending out the single byte 0x37 over and over again, and that's what I saw in the data stream)

We then started the small box generating data again, and saw the same behavior: 4435 bytes were seen, after which we get no bytes from the UART, despite a two minute flood of bytes at 921600 bps.

Here is the receive thread

```
 void RecieveThread()
  {
      int n;

      while (continueRecieving)
      {
          n = connectorPort.BytesToRead;

          byte[] bits = new byte[n];

          if (n > 0)
          {
              connectorPort.Read(bits, 0, n);
          }

          Write(bits);
      }
  }
```

Just in case anyone feels it's important, here is the Write(bits) routine

```
 public void Write(byte[] b)
 {
     if (writting)
     {
         for (int i = 0; i < b.Length; i++)
         {
             storage[sPlace++] = b[i];

             pass += b[i].ToString("X2") + " ";

             if (sPlace % numericUpDown1.Value == 0)
             {
                 pass += "\r\n";
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Has anyone previously experienced disappearing bluetooth bytes on a Win7 machine with a C# app ?

Can anyone see an obvious (or obscure) error which could be causing this ?

Comment: A couple of hints that may or may not help: You might want to throw a Sleep in there if BytesToRead is zero. Also, you allocate an array and call Write even if n == 0, which could burn cycles unnecessarily. Finally, you'll probably want to reuse the same array rather than recreating it over and over in a high-performance scenario like this.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, I added a slight delay between the data bursts. I now get an error in the software elsewhere; an index goes out of bounds. So it looks like you were correct, or at least close enough to give me an idea.  Now for the out of bounds index.